# Swing and javafx

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I am trying to put a resized media player in a swing tabbed pane. The only way I can find to resize the media is to use a media view. But when I try to add the controller I get MediaControl cannot be cast to javafx.scene.Group.

My code is;

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;

public class JavaFX_insideTab {

private static final String MEDIA_URL = "http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv";

private static void initFxLater(JFXPanel panel) {
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 450, 200);
    // create media player
    Media media = new Media(MEDIA_URL);
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);

    MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);

    mediaView.setFitWidth(450);
    mediaView.setFitHeight(200);

    MediaControl mediaControl = new MediaControl(mediaPlayer);
    scene.setRoot(mediaControl);

    ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(mediaView);

        panel.setScene(scene);
}

private static void initSwingLater() {
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("- JFrame -");
    jFrame.setSize(540, 426);
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    final JFXPanel jFXPanel = new JFXPanel();
    jFXPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 540, 188);

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    tabbedPane.setBounds(0, 0, 528, 392);
    jFrame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("New tab", null, panel, null);
    JPanel playerpanel = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("Media Player", null, playerpanel, null);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    playerpanel.add(jFXPanel);

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
    initFxLater(jFXPanel);
    }
    });

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

@Override
    public void run() {
        initSwingLater();
    }

    });
}
```

}

where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming [this is your MediaControl](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/MediaControl.java.htm), then it is already a [Parent](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html) subclass, so you don't need to place it in a parent [Group](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Group.html).

You can use the following code:

```
private static void initFxLater(JFXPanel panel) {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(new Media(MEDIA_URL));
    mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);

    MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
    mediaView.setFitWidth(450);
    mediaView.setFitHeight(200);

    panel.setScene(new Scene(new MediaControl(mediaPlayer));
}
```

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "resize the media", but the above code will always size the media to fit within the bounding box of size 450x200 (with the default of preserving the size ratio of the media).

Comment: Thanks for your answer it gets me closer to my goal. However this seems to produce a 10mm high player with an unscaled movie. What I am trying to do is create a small (400 x 200 ish) scaled movie with a media control on a tabbed pane. By a scaled movie I mean that the all of the movie fits in the 400 x 200 control. I hope this helps.